# Security validation error when try get data from sharepoint using silverlight

Tags: silverlight, security, sharepoint, silverlight-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I try to execute this code in Silcerlight 4 contol hosted in webpart:

```
clientCtx = new ClientContext(ApplicationContext.Current.Url);
clientCtx.ValidateOnClient = true;
clientCtx.Load(clientCtx.Web);
clientCtx.ExecuteQueryAsync(updateConnectionStatus, Failed);
```

but it fails and go Failed method and I recive error: "The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again."

When I turn off security validation in central administration everything works. How to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have a cross-domain posting issue.  See the following SO question that deails how to provision the clientaccesspolicy.xml file to prevent cross-domain posting issues.

[How can I add a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file to the SharePoint 2010 root folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302825/how-can-i-add-a-clientaccesspolicy-xml-file-to-the-sharepoint-2010-root-folder)